# Trying to understand memory leaks with NULL in c

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks, null

I created a small test in order to create memory leaks and testing the leaks in terminal using leaks command. Now I encountered a strange behavior with the NULL. So any explanation why the other code leaks, and the other one doesn't? Aren't they really the same?

```
int     main(void)
{
    char *ptr;
    char *btr;

    ptr = NULL;
    btr = (char*)malloc(4);
    btr = ptr;
    while (1)
        ;
    return (0);
}
    // LEAKS

int     main(void)
{
    char *btr;

    btr = (char*)malloc(4);
    btr = NULL;
    while (1)
        ;
    return (0);
}
    //NO LEAKS ?? why
```

Comment: How did you check the leak?

Comment: What exactly is determining this "leaks" vs "no leaks"? It seems that either you have fooled your analyzer or some compiler optimization is making the code different.

Comment: Also, don't cast the return value of `malloc`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc (unrelated to the question)

Comment: How are you determining the leak? Are you taking into consideration compiler optimizations?

Comment: I guess you are using the OS X [leaks](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/leaks/) command?

Comment: Yes, OS X leaks command.

Comment: You may need to add `-fno-builtin-malloc` (or just `-fno-builtin`) option to the compiler command line to prevent the compiler optimizing out the call to `malloc`.

Comment: Tried out -fno-builtin (and -O0) but still shows no leaks in the second case.

Answer (score 1):

If anything I would hazard that you have compiler optimisation turned on.
In the second example this will likely ignore the line

```
btr = (char*)malloc(4);
```

during compilation as you immediately set the result to NULL.

Comment: Is it allowed to do that? Isn't it supposed to call `malloc` for its side effects?

Comment: Further to my comment above [5.1.2.3p4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.3p4) says "In the abstract machine, all expressions are evaluated as specified by the semantics. An actual implementation need not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its value is not used and that **no needed side effects** are produced (including any caused by calling a function or accessing a volatile object)." (emphasis mine). But I wonder what criteria determine whether a side effect is _needed_?

Comment: gcc does indeed optimize out the call to `malloc` and it seems to be solely based on the function name matching a built-in function name, regardless of whether `<stdlib.h>` has been `#include`d or not.

Comment: Adding the `-fno-builtin` option to the gcc command line prevents it from optimizing out the call to `malloc`.

Comment: Hmm. No effect with -fno-builtin or -O0, but if I add printf("%p",ptr) after btr = NULL; it will then show the leak. But compiler optimization seems a reasonable cause.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't comment, but some people have commented that it would the result of compiler optimization.

However, if we copy the original non-leaky code and change the value to a larger number, we can clearly see that it is allocating memory:

```
int     main(void)
{
    char *btr;

    btr = (char*)malloc(1000000);
    btr = NULL;
    while (1)
        ;
    return (0);
}
```

Leaks output:

```
Process 9945: 162 nodes malloced for 994 KB
Process 9945: 0 leaks for 0 total leaked bytes.
```

If we comment the allocation out:

```
Process 10070: 161 nodes malloced for 14 KB
Process 10070: 0 leaks for 0 total leaked bytes.
```

So clearly the allocation does happen and leaks is aware of it (+1 node, +circa 1 MiB). If the compiler (clang, Hive Mac default settings, no special flags) has supposedly optimised it out, how can leaks know about the allocation?